# Python if statement: less than

Tags: python, if-statement, limit

Ok, can someone tell me how to make an if else statement with a character limit

i wrote a quick code to make you see what am trying to tell you

```
pass1 = input("What is you'r password: ")
pass2 = input("Rewrite you'r password: ")
```

what i tried:

```
if pass1 == <5:
   print ("password is greater than 5")
else:
   print ("password is lower than 5")
```

basically am trying to make a limit like in real website when you register (when you register there's a character limit example it cant be lower than 5 characters).

Comment: You have to decide if you want it to be equal (`==`) or less than (`<`) something. You cannot have both... Well, you actually can (`<=`)

Comment: So, in words, you're trying to test whether the *length* of `pass1` is less than 5. Aptly, this is expressed as `len(pass1) < 5` in python.

Answer (score 7):

You need to test the *length* of the string with [`len`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=built%20functions#len) function:

```
if len(pass1) < 5:
```

Perhaps you may have some confusion also with `if` statements and arithmetic operators. Check them here:

1. [Control Flow](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)
2. [Comparissons](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in)